# Running Page Specific Javascript in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates

I am working on a project which allows users to monitor energy consumption. The main dashboard page is a web app which is pretty neat and makes extensive use of javascript and ajax. The server currently runs apache and uses php; however, I am planning on installing node.js and updating the server side scripts in order to support websockets (and I also like the idea of using javascript on the server and client side).

I have followed several online introductions but I am struggling to find answers to specific questions which I need to get my head round before I can start, one of which is outlined below.

Is there a simple way to run page-specific javascript on the pages of the website in the same way you would with PHP? I have come across templating (for example using mustache), but I don't understand whether it is possible to run specific modules of javascript on the server when a specific file is about to be served.

*Thank you very much for taking the time to read my questions. If you can answer any of them, or even provide any general advice, it would be greatly appreciated.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be looking into web frameworks for Node.js that help you with this kind of thing.  My favorite is [express](http://expressjs.com/).

Express will allow you to map a "route" to a handler, and that handler can be in any file you want.  E.g.,

`app.get('/energy/page-x', require('./routes/page-x-handler'));`

Where `./routes/page-x-handler.js` is something like:

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('template-name');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use a framework like [Express](http://expressjs.com/) you can 'intercept' (or 'route', as it's called) requests for specific URL's and run server side JS to handle that URL (including, at the end of processing, render and return a template).

One of the differences with PHP is that PHP often mixes templates and code into one file, whereas with Node, those two are usually separated (so you have a clear separation between code and layout).